# Linq Grouping for data Table

Tags: c#, linq

As I am new to LINQ  and I am struggling writing group query for following datatable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Files");

dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
    new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)), 
    new DataColumn("FileName", typeof(string)), 
    new DataColumn("ParentID", typeof(int)) 
} );

dt.Rows.Add(1, "File1.Jpg", 1);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "File2.jpg", 1);
dt.Rows.Add(3, "File3.jpg", 1);
dt.Rows.Add(4, "File3.jpg", 1);
dt.Rows.Add(5, "File4.jpg", 1);
dt.Rows.Add(6, "File3.jpg", 2);
```

I need the result of "file3.jpg" for given parentID = 1. How can I achieve this ? 
I tried a lot of solutions which did not work for me. Also, is there a way to get result as datarow?. please let me know if you know any resources such as website, books etc that you recommend.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the result of "file3.jpg" for given parentID = 1" ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DataRow dr = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x("ID")) == 3 && 
                             Convert.ToInt32(x("ParentID")) == 1)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: hi nikhil i need the result of repeated values only

Answer (score 0):

By what you are saying u need to get all values that have parentID = 1 and that FileName = file3.jpg.If thats the case you can use DataView,by your example you have 2 records with those values(the ones with id 3 and 4) so to get those values with dataview you do this:

```
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt); //dt is your datatable.
            dv.RowFilter = "ParentID = '1' AND FileName = 'File3.jpg'";
            for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dv[i]["ID"] + " - " + dv[i]["FileName"]);
            }
```

EDIT:

ok if its just with linq and to get the first "File3.jpg" and as a datarow:

```
DataRow dr = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r["ParentID"].ToString() == "1" && r["FileName"].ToString() == "File3.jpg");
```

Comment: Even though the OP is using `DataTable`s they specifically asked for a Linq solution.

Comment: terry what i expect is only repeated value of filename for particular parentid

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => (int)x["ParentID"] == 1)
             .GroupBy(x => x["FileName"]).Where(x=>x.Count() > 1)
             .Select(x => x.Key);
```

### UPDATE

If you want to ignore case, try add a `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` as the second parameter into `GroupBy<...>`, something like this:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => (int)x["ParentID"] == 1)
             .GroupBy<DataRow,string>(x => x["FileName"].ToString(), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
             .Where(x=>x.Count() > 1)
             .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks King, this is what i exactly need. but one more thing if i add two more rows dt.Rows.Add(7, "File4.jpg", 1); dt.Rows.Add(8, "File1.jpg", 1); its dosen't return File1.jpg. after that i realise the first row contains dt.Rows.Add(1, "File1.Jpg", 1); which has Caps "J" letter in extension and i changed the groupby as GroupBy(x => x["cFileName"].ToString().ToUpper()). my doubt is linq depends on case sensitive in grouping?

Comment: @user1599700 yes, the default culture is case-sensitive. Please see my update, you can also use `ToUpper()` or `ToLower()` as you did.